# How to open the last locked door in the village

Tags: candy-box-2

In the village, the door on the far left is locked, despite me completely beating the game in terms of levels and inventory. How can I open that locked door? The last 2 things I need to do is open this door and beat the arcade games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but on [the wiki,](http://candybox2.net/wiki) there is no "fourth house" in the village that you can enter. There is a locked house, but according to this line in the wiki about the village:
Each of these areas can be accessed except for the first locked house
So, you cannot unlock it.